# Send Correct Data Fetched to my Model via API

Tags: c#, .net

When I fetch data from my Basket API to further on post to my OrderLine API I get this back in JSON:

```
 [
     {
            "productId": 1,
            "quantity": 1
      }
  ]
```

but my OrderLine API accepts the following:

```
{
  "productId": 0,
  "quantity": 0
}
```

I want to send the data fetched from my Basket API to my OrderLine so that the following is returned:

```
{
  "orderID": 0,
  "identifier": "string",
  "customer": "string",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "productId": 0,
      "quantity": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Where "items" is the data fetched from my Basket.

This is what my API GET Basket looks like for fetching data from basket:

```
 // GET: https://localhost:5500/api/Basket/{identifier}
        [HttpGet("/basket/{identifier}")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<OrderLineDTO>> GetBasketItems(string identifier)
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
               HttpMethod.Get,
               $"https://localhost:5500/api/Basket/{identifier}")
            {
                Headers = { { HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json" }, }
            };

            var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

            using var httpResponseMessage =
                await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

            var items = Enumerable.Empty<OrderLineDTO>();

            if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return items;

            using var contentStream =
                await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

            var basketDto = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
                    <OrderDTO>(contentStream, options);

            items = basketDto.Items.Select(x =>
                new OrderLineDTO
                {
                    ProductId = x.ProductId,
                    Quantity = x.Quantity,
                }
            );

            var entryJson = new StringContent(
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(items),
                Encoding.UTF8,
                Application.Json);
            
            await httpClient.PostAsync($"http://localhost:5700/api/OrderLine", entryJson);

            return items; // 200 OK
        }
```

And this is my Post to OrderLine:

```
 // POST: api/OrderLine
        [HttpPost("/api/OrderLine")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Order>> PostOrderLine(OrderLine orderLine)
        {
            _context.OrderLine.Add(orderLine);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetOrder", new { id = orderLine.Id }, orderLine);
        }
```

This is my OrderLineDTO:

```
public class OrderLineDTO
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my OrderLine model:

```
 public class OrderLine
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

Does anybody know how to solve this? Thanks in advance for any help, I'm just hoping to get the corresponding fetched data from my Basket API then send in back to OrderLine

EDIT:
Also added my OrderDTO which is callled upon in my GET Basket Method:

```
 public class OrderDTO
    {
        
        public string Identifier { get; set; }

        public string Customer { get; set; }

        public List<OrderLine> Items { get; set; } = new List<OrderLine>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `items` which is an object of type `OrderLineDTO`

What you want to return is an object of type `OrderDTO`

Comment: I thought of that too, I'll try it again but I don't think I quite understood how. Last time I tried I didn't get the data fetched back properly from my BasketAPI, I only got {
  "productId": 0,
  "quantity": 0
} back ( 0 returned as value when in fact there was another value ). Any idea how to do this?

Comment: 1. The return type of the method GetBasketItems(string identifier) should be 
async Task<IEnumerable<OrderDTO>>

2. You have to deserialize the response from API to an OrderDTO object and return it.

Comment: Like this? var basketDto = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
                    <OrderDTO>(contentStream, options); Thanks for helping out by the way

Comment: yes, and then return basketDto. Also why are you sending a POST-Request inside a GET-Request?

Comment: I'm using this GET Method to get the "items" from the Basket API which in return I want to Post to my OrderLine as {
  "productId": 0,
  "quantity": 0
} That's why I'm using a PostAsync inside my GET

Comment: But how do I choose the ProductId and Quantity keys when I'm using OrderDTO as the argument in <IEnumerable<OrderDTO>>